# Magento 2 from Bitnami on Amazon Lightsail VPS servers won't upgrade and requires reindexing all the time

Tags: magento-2.1, amazon-web-services

I've been testing this for the last day or so and it seems to be working fine (though slow as h*ll sometimes, considering I'm using the free tier server).

But I'm havinge some minor issues though. Bear in mind that this might all be due to way too low hardware specs for Magento 2 considering that the Amazon Lightsail free tier VPS is a 1vCPU, 512MB RAM server with 20gb diskspace.

Even still, before consider paying for a more beefed up server I would like some opinions on whether the following issues are due to hardware, the bitnami Magento Package or perhaps something else.

1. I cannot upgrade from Magento 2.1.2 to 2.1.3, in the Magento upgrade "Readyness check" gives the very generic error message "We found conflicting component dependencies." And no additional info.
   Could this be due to the low specs on the VPS server?
2. Almost every action I perform in the administrator console for Magento will result in one of the indexes being required to reindex. This happens basically all of the time, again - is this perhaps due to the low amount of memory or is it a known issue with Magento 2 or the Bitnami set-up of Magento?

Besides this, the set up seems to be working suprisingly well for such a low spec server so I'm really considering getting a more beefed up version, I just wanted some input from anyone here who might know if these issues can be resolved as soon as I get bigger and better hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the RAM limit on that free tier server was way too low for Magento..